# Smarty and Kohana

Tags: php, kohana, smarty, kohana-3

Is there a standard "official" way of using Smarty with Kohana 3? I see there are [some options](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/3708/kohana-3-smarty-module/p1) that seem less than ideal and will probably break when either Smarty or Kohana's minor version number increases.

(as a side question, is it a good idea to use Smarty with Kohana? I'm only trying to have it installed because I'm very familiarized with Smarty and I'm afraid Kohana won't provide all the stuff I love about Smarty..)

Comment: You might want to consider using [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/) instead of Smarty. There is already a [module](https://github.com/jheathco/kohana-twig) for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ko3 supports plain php views "from the box", any other template engine can be added as module. This is "standard official" way to extend Ko3 framework features.

If you need a better module, you can modify/extend existing one for your purposes. A lot of people are using templates like Smarty, Dwoo, Twig etc, so dont afraid ;)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use or create a module that overrides the built in Kohana::View. There is an existing module already available so you don't need to create one yourself:

**KSmarty:** https://bitbucket.org/dfox/ksmarty/wiki/Home